# Failed to locate Element from a CheckOut Table

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I'm not able to locate an element. I want to `getText()` from the element then convert it to a float and calculate. However, can't seem to find element.

```
String unitPrice = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".price")).getText();
        //By.xpath(".//*[@id='product_1_1_0_0']/td[4]")).getText();
String unit = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".cart_quantity_input.form-control.grey")).getText();
        //By.xpath(".//*[@id='product_1_1_0_0']/td[5]/input[2]")).getText();
String totalPrice = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#total_product_price_1_1_0")).getText();
        //By.xpath(".//*[@id='total_product_price_1_1_0']")).getText();

float unitPriceF = Float.parseFloat(unitPrice);
float unitF = Float.parseFloat(unit);
float TotalPriceF = Float.parseFloat(totalPrice);
```

I've tried both xPath and cssSelector, but getting same error in both cases:

> no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
>   selector","selector":"#total_product_price_1_1_0"}(..)

This is the HTML structure :

```
<div id="order-detail-content" class="table_block table-responsive">
<table id="cart_summary" class="table table-bordered stock-management-on">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="cart_product first_item">Product</th>
<th class="cart_description item">Description</th>
<th class="cart_avail item">Avail.</th>
<th class="cart_unit item">Unit price</th>
<th class="cart_quantity item">Qty</th>
<th class="cart_total item">Total</th>
<th class="cart_delete last_item"> </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
<tr class="cart_total_price">
<td id="cart_voucher" class="cart_voucher" rowspan="3" colspan="3"> </td>
<td class="text-right" colspan="3">Total products</td>
<td id="total_product" class="price" colspan="2">$39.51</td>
</tr>
<tr style="display: none;">
<tr class="cart_total_delivery">
<tr class="cart_total_voucher" style="display:none">
<tr class="cart_total_price">
</tfoot>
<tbody>
<tr id="product_1_1_0_0" class="cart_item last_item first_item address_0 odd">
<td class="cart_product">
<td class="cart_description">
<td class="cart_avail">
<td class="cart_unit" data-title="Unit price">
<span id="product_price_1_1_0" class="price">
<span class="price">$39.51</span>
</span>
</td>
<td class="cart_quantity text-center">
<td class="cart_total" data-title="Total">
<td class="cart_delete text-center" data-title="Delete">
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the rows from the table first:

```
 List <WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
```

Use the row number to get the cell in the row:

```
 String unitPrice= rows.get(1).findElement(By.cssSelector(".price")).getText();
```

The above line would return string *`$39.51`* and you cannot directly convert this to float because of the *`$`* symbol. Split the string before converting to float

Comment: cool boss, i actually got something this time. I put quantity 2 and the total price i got is: $79.02. so it was actually the total. unitPrice: 39.51, quantity 2, Total $79.02

Answer (score 1):

Try to select the element with the Text you want:

```
String price = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#product_1_1_0_0 > td:nth-child(4) > span > span")).getText();
```

[image]

This should work, so long as the ID `#product_1_1_0_0` is not dynamic. Your element not found exception leads me to believe it is dynamic. If that is the case ignore that id and go up the hierarchy a bit with the selector:

```
"#cart_summary > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(4) > span > span"
```

**EDIT**

I just noticed the id="product_price_1_1_0" on the first span, so you could just do:

```
"#product_price_1_1_0 > span"
```

Comment: Hi Timothy, thanks for your help. However both locators failed. is there any other way to get the value?


no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#product_1_1_0_0 > td:nth-child(4) > span > span"}(..)

no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#cart_summary > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(4) > span > span"}(..)

Answer (score 1):

To get the price first, find the row with its id. our price is in the span tag in that row. Now, get those span tag elements into the "List", our price is in the second span element. So, get that element and use ".getText()" to get the data.

```
     WebElement row = driver.findElement(By.id("product_1_1_0_0"));
     List<WebElement> span = row.findElements(By.tagName("span"));
     String totalPrice = span.get(1).getText();
```

Comment: Thanks KK but still got the same error: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"product_1_1_0_0"}(..)